# nginx: access log control while maintaining internal redirection to WordPress

Tags: nginx, redirect, wordpress

I created a WordPress page with permalink `http://domain.tld/health_status` for WordPress health monitoring. It's accessed frequently, so I don't want these requests to appear in my access log.

The basic "rewrite rule" for all WordPress pages is:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$args;
}
```

Now, on the same level, I tried

```
location /health_status {
    access_log off;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$args;
    }
```

From the nginx [location documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location):

> Literal strings match the beginning portion of the query - the most
>   specific match will be used

`/health_status` is more specific than `/`, so this block takes action when I request `http://domain.tld/health_status`.

With the `try_files` line commented out (as above), the request does not show up in the access log, hurray, but obviously I just get a 404 error, because nginx does not redirect this request to WordPress.

With the `try_files` line being active, an internal redirect to WordPress' `index.php` takes place and the `/health_status` WordPress page is shown in the browser. However, after the internal redirect the `location /health_status` block is not in action anymore and the request ends up in the access log.

How to solve this problem cleanly? Do I now have to add another block matching the actual `/index.php?q=healthstatuswhatever` request that takes place after the internal redirect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a named location for requests destined for WordPress. An example of this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_ ### fastcgi params and other config for PHP go here
}

location @wordpress {
    try_files $uri /index.php;

    fastcgi_ ### fastcgi params and other config for WP go here
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @wordpress;
}

location /health_status {
    access_log off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @wordpress;
}
```

This example is incomplete and may be insecure; it only demonstrates how your issue may be resolved. Be sure to secure your web server properly.

Comment: I did not try it yet (will soon). Thanks for your answer so far. Two questions arise: 1) I don't quite get why this should work. Does the internal redirect to a named location keep the `access_log` setting "active" while an internal redirect to a real location does not? Can you point me to the corresponding documentation? 2) Does your approach in any way affect performance negatively (just out of curiosity)?